# What happens when an youtube swf file is buffered

Tags: youtube, flash

Whenever a youtube or any other flash content is buffered on the browser, isn't it true that is downloaded to the client computer ? So my assumption is that, any completely buffered youtube file should be found on my client right ?
   For example, when i view [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbUtL_0vAJk) video on youtube, i see that it is actually referring to this swf location 'http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swf/watch_as3-vfl144654.swf'. How does youtube actually buffer this video on my computer then ?

Note: My objective is NOT to download youtube videos as i know there are extensions available for it. I just want to know how it works :) .

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Your browser downloads the video. Look into the cache for suspiciously big files. These are flvs.

Comment: Flash plays back H.264 `.mp4` directly these days; formats aren't just limited to `.flv`.

Comment: Checked C:\Users\<uname>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2xsie03b.default\Cache
but found no swf files in there :(